# Error using HTML to PDF conversion using Essential objects

Tags: c#, html, pdf

I have used the following code to convert from html to pdf using EO

```
 private void CreatePDFFromHtml(string strFilePath, string strFileExt)
        {
            string strGetFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(strFilePath);
            string strFileLocation = txtTarget.Text + "\\" + strGetFileName.Replace(strFileExt, ".pdf");
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(strFileLocation))
            {
                File.Delete(strFileLocation);
            }
            HtmlToPdf.ConvertHtml(strGetFileName, strFileLocation);

        }
```

However the output that i get is completely blank in the pdf file. 
I have installed it using nuget install-package EO.pdf

Comment: I have used .net framework 4. not sure why its not working , can anyone please point out the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out the problem. In the first parameter for HTMLToPDF.ConvertHtml(string html, pdfdocument)
I had supplied the html file name, it was expecting the actual html in string format.